# Compare two regression models for a given test set in R

Tags: r, regression, model-selection

I formulated two linear models to fit the data from my dataset. 
I split the dataset into a training, validation, and test partition.

Since I have two models I want to know which one predicts better given the test set.

If I am correct, the model is built with the train and validation sets, and the predictions are compared with the test set. 
Due to my limited knowledge of statistics, my first approach would be to calculate the Mean Squared Error (MSE) and select the model with the lower MLE.

I am sure there are better approaches but I only find cross validation examples on the web, and nothing straight forward.

I tried using `anova` but I think it compares the models for the set they where built to predict using `lm`.

Comment: So what's not straightforward from the cross-validation examples you found? I mean, you are doing a cross-validation exercise here so those examples should be relevant.